# How to build LLVM source code on Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, ubuntu, llvm

I am trying to add a new pass to the llvm compiler infrastructure.
I have been able to build LLVM-2.9 using make.But I wants to build using Eclipse
so that I can trace the code.
    I imported llvm source files to c++ project with LinuxGcc tool chain 
and CDT internal builder(Eclipse with CDT-7.0).But it gives some errors.
    Is this is a right way to build llvm using eclipse?.
Please suggest me steps involved to build llvm source using Eclipse.
Note: Platform ubuntu.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`cmake -G"Eclipse CDT4 - Unix Makefiles"`](http://www.itk.org/Wiki/Eclipse_CDT4_Generator) to produce the native Eclipse set of projects. It might require tweaking your `CMakeLists.txt` to remove the check for in-source builds (since Eclipse can only support project files and sources in the same directory, but for some reason the current CMakeLists allows it for MSVS only) - just follow the error messages.

Answer (score 7):

1. Tools/versions used by me:

   - eclipse 4.3 Kepler, CDT 8.2.1
   - Oracle Java SDK 1.7.0_45
   - cmake 2.8.11.2
   - LLVM 3.5svn
2. Create a folder for CDT project files in your workspace. *I.e.* `workspace/llvm`.
3. Generate CDT project files with cmake (being in `workspace/llvm`):

   ```
   cmake -G "Eclipse CDT4 - Unix Makefiles" -D_ECLIPSE_VERSION=4.3 ../../src/llvm
   ```

   If eclipse version is not set the generator will assume 3.7 and inform you that it can be changed by `CMAKE_ECLIPSE_VERSION` option, what turns out to be the wrong name for that option.
4. Increase eclipse heap allocation size. The default setting is too small and C++ Indexer would hang the whole IDE. Replace default settings with

   ```
   -Xms512m
   -Xmx1024m
   ```

   in `eclipse.ini` file.
5. Import the project into your workspace. File → Import... → General → Existing Projects into Workspace.
6. The project `llvm` can be built as one (option Build Project). There are also separated targets created for every lib and executable, placed in `[Targets]` folder. Individual target can be built with option Make Targets → Build...

Comment: I was able to build LLVM + Clang using your answer. Now I am facing an issue regarding the time it takes for the indexer to cover all the source files. Do you have any tip on how one could decrease this indexing time ?