# eclipse cdt indexer getting stuck in llvm project

Tags: eclipse, clang, llvm

I am trying to build llvm project on eclipse. After building the project the indexer is kicking in, however every time it getting stuck on macro_pounder_fn.c file with the error :

```
An internal error has occurred.
GC overhead limit exceeded
```

or sometimes eclipse just crash. I followed [How to build LLVM source code on Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7125857/how-to-build-llvm-source-code-on-eclipse) but t is still happening...
How can I solve it ?

***update:***
the indexer is stuck on the file - cxx-ambig-init-temple.cpp

Answer (score 0):

There are/were some known EclipseCDT issues in this regard, specifically for the LLVM/clang sources:

- https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=364188
- https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=257905

I tried to increase the JVM stack size (add -Xss1m in eclipse.ini) as depicted in Issue #364188, but without success for me.

However EclipseCDT's indexer gets stuck in some test files of Clang that are not necessary to build clang itself, so you can remove them manually and build clang successfully but you won't be able to perform those automated tests.

As you pointed out, the problematic file is:
llvm/tools/clang/test/Perser/cxx-ambig-init-temple.cpp